# Reading complicated format CSV fileinto Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, input, import-from-csv

My raw CSV file looks like the 1st pic. And I wants to use Matlab read it into the format as the 2rd pic. I have over 1000 the same kind of CSV files, it will be painful if I do it by copy/paste. How can I do this? Any examples?

raw data: [image: Raw Data]

output data: [image: Output Data]

Answer (score 0):

First thing to realize is that a .csv file has a very simple format.  Your above file is actually a plain text file with the following text on each line:

```
id,A001
height
a1,a2,a3
3,4,5
3,4,5
6,7,5

weight
a1,a2,a3
4,4,5
5,4,6
i6,7,5
```

So it is not all that hard for you to write your own parser in Matlab.  You want to use commands like

```
fid = fopen('filename.csv','r');
L = fgetl(fid); % get a text line from the file
commas = find(L==','); % find where the commas are in the line
n1 = str2num(L(1:commas(1)-1); % convert the first comma-delimited number on line L
fidout - fopen('myfile.csv','w');
Lout =  [ L(commas(2)+1:commas(3)-1) ', a1, a1'];
fwrite(fidout,Lout); % write a line out to the output file
fclose all; % close all open files.
```

It will seem slow at first reading the various values in to various variables, and then arranging them to write out the way you want them written out to your output file.  But once you get rolling it will go pretty fast and you will find yourself with a pretty good understanding of what is in files, and you will know first hand what is involved in writing something like `texscan.m` or `csvwrite.m` and so on.

Good luck!